# Single word for someone who is being impersonated ("impersonatee"?)

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, er-ee

I'm writing about impersonators and people being impersonated in general terms and having 'the impersonator' and 'the person being impersonated' is cumbersome at best.

'Impersonatee' sort of works, but isn't great. Any ideas?

Comment: How about *victim*?

Comment: The '*owner-of-the-hair-whose-polyjuice-potion-the-impersonator-drank*'? :)

Comment: Victim is good except for the negative connotation

Comment: *Original* can work, but I don't think it fits for people.

Comment: *Target* is more neutral than *victim*. Or something along the lines of *role* or *identity*. That being said, *-ee* is productive, and *impersonatee* would be universally understood.

Comment: I have a similar problem, I am indicating in a database, one column stating the user id of the person who is doing the impersonation, the "impersonator". The word that jumps out at me is the proposed "impersonatee" for the person who is being impersonated. "UserIDOfPersonToImpersonate" seems cumbersome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Subject***
 
The person being depicted or portrayed by a painter, an artist, or in this case an impersonator.

> The impersonator's favourite [subjects](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/subject_1) were politicians and well-known
>   singers.

---

**Edit**
One of Britain's most famous and loved impersonators during the 1970s and early '80s was Mike Yarwood. Yarwood enjoyed stratospheric popularity in the years when British television only had three channels. In the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Yarwood#Decline) dedicated to the entertainer the term, *subjects*, is used.

> Most of his most famous **subjects**, such as Heath and Wilson, retired
>   from public life or died and he was unable to master new prominent
>   figures, most significantly, the country's first woman Prime Minister,
>   Margaret Thatcher.

Answer (score 7):

I really think that you can make do with good old [nominal adjectives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective), which act almost like nouns.

> In the sentence, "I read two books to them; he preferred the sad book, but she preferred the happy", happy is a nominal adjective, short for "happy one" or "happy book".

Therefore: ***the impersonated***.

I don't see why you've all decided to ignore that. How is *the impersonated* less of a noun than *impersonatee* or *impersonate*?

Comment: Would impersonated indicate that it happened in the past? Whereas the proposed impersonatee would be indifferent to the tense? I'm unsure myself, just a conversation piece.

Answer (score 1):

"Impersonatee" should be considered a technical term. I have scoured the internet and it is used in places like Wikipedia, Oracle, SAP,CA Technologies. It seems to be mostly used to describe a user within an computer application that will be impersonated by an administrator. This is used to help troubleshoot/debug for customer service when a user is having a problem with that application. I vote to add this to the dictionary.

Example from [Oracle's Fusion Middleware Administering Oracle WebCenter Portal](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/webcenter.1111/e27738/wcadm_impersonate.htm#WCADM11049):

> WebCenter Portal Impersonation lets a WebCenter Portal administrator or system administrator assign impersonation rights to a group of users ("impersonators"), such as support representatives or application administrators, so that they can perform operations as other users ("impersonatees"). Note that this is subject to the impersonatee granting the impersonator additional rights to impersonate them.

Comment: Hi Tony, and welcome to our site. If you've found references to the word, please cite them in your answer, preferably with both examples and links. We rely on this added reference material to be able to distinguish between mere opinion (and perhaps incorrect opinion at that) and an authoritative answer. For further guidance, see [answer]. Make sure you also take the **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: To whom are you submitting this vote, Tony?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of **character** or **personality**. Advise if wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[imitatee](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imitatee) - "One that is imitated" (from Merriam-Webster)

Admittedly, that's the only mainstream online dictionary I can find it in, but it may be in larger print dictionaries.

Comment: My copy of the American Heritage Dictionary (which is 2100 pages long, approx, with a spine-length of about a foot) does not have '*imitatee*'. :)

Comment: I just checked the OED; it returned: _No dictionary entries found for ‘imitatee’._ It's certainly not a common word.

Comment: Imitatee is a technical term. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3574936/ http://psycnet.apa.org/psycinfo/1935-04184-001 Not really used for impersonators.

Comment: As I suspected.

Answer (score 0):

You can call them a ***model***.

The dictionary definition of *model* applicable in this instance is

> a person or thing that serves as a subject for an artist, sculptor, writer, etc.
>
> a standard to be imitated: *she was my model for good scholarship*

eg. *Elvis is a popular model for impersonators*.

Comment: My first thought was, "Wait! A model is something you try to copy or replicate, not impersonate," but then I thought, _"Well, impersonators certainly try to copy..."_ Still, this answer sounds not-quite-right for some reason. It vexes me, but in a very good way.

Comment: It's probably a good choice for certain examples (like entertainers) but not others (like identity theft).